# Custom LED Assembly manufacturing?

Tags: led, manufacturing

I would like to fab some custom LEDs Assemblies.

Embed a resistor in the plastic, is there a smart way to go about doing this?

I know Alibaba other than that nothing really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom plastic could be expensive. I would find a lens you like
and fabricate a small PCB with an SMD resistor and SMD LED. Glue the 
lens to the PCB. Add two pins for the external connection.

Comment: While will not knocking someone's attempt to rediscover lost arts or replicating the experiments done in the past, it's unlikely you'd be as successful as a modern led.

Comment: I could be wrong but I was reading this as "I would like to fab some custom LED assemblies".

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a led with a built-in series resistor, I believe these are available already.

Answer (score 0):

How many? For anything less than thousands it would probably be cheaper to solder a resistor to an LED and pot the whole assembly in acrylic